# recording video with opencv

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, video

I used this example to record a video, but there is no output. Any help, please:

```
import cv2

if __ name __ == " __ main __ ":

    # find the webcam

    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    # video recorder
    fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')  # cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc() does not exist
    videoOut = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

    # record video
    while (capture.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        if ret:
            videoOut.write(frame)
            cv2.imshow('Video Stream', frame)

        else:
             break

        # Tiny Pause
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    capture.release()
    videoOut.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I got this error:

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP

(Video Stream:2758): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run it in headless mode. A bug/feature of some OpenCV things is that it's **a must-have** requirement to be run *from Xterm of already working X11/GUI*. Weird, but the root of the problem is that it uses some external components like video codecs in your case via GUI-related component HighUI. If you have a working and running X11/GUI but still have this error - make sure to set the environment variable DISPLAY to your X11 display **and** after setting it via `export` command, run your program like `DISPLAY=xx:yy your_binary` via env importing on-exec.

Comment: I tried it with a HDMI cable but I got the same error

Comment: @happy from GUI Xterm?

Comment: no,but normally with hdmi we can display it no??

Comment: @happy if you haven't exported a DISPLAY variable - no, a headless call **is headless literally**

Comment: haw can I exported it ???

Comment: @happy in a shell. make a shell script, use bash and state `export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0` and next string `DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0 your_binary`

Comment: ok thank you but can you explain to me the second command DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0 your_binary

Comment: the execution string. first, you're exporting a variable on first string, second string - a fail-safe export-on-call of the environment variable DISPLAY, that points *any* X11 call explicitly to the point specified. 127.0.0.1:0 or 127.0.0.1:0.0 are the default X11 server endpoint

Comment: the same error :(

Comment: OK, try from inside an XTerm inside your GUI *from the HDMI-attached console*

Comment: @happy if it won't help - write it, I'll help you to build it from source : two times I had a very *odd* bugs from repository-based distributions of OpenCV

Comment: I am just a beginner perhaps the problem is in the code it self !!

Comment: @happy maybe, but it's not a 100% warranty